Can we get a homomorphism between two elliptic curves if we know a homomorphism between the respective formal groups?
Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be two elliptic curves over a field of characteristic $0$, and let $\hat{E_1}$ and $\hat{E_2}$ be two formal group laws associated with $E_1$ and $E_2$, respectively. It is known that an isogeny $\phi: E_1 \to E_2$ induces a homomorphism $\phi^*: \hat{E_1} \to \hat{E_2}$.
$\phi^*$ captures local properties of $E_1$ and $E_2$ near the identities, whereas $\phi$ is a global homomorphism between $E_1$ and $E_2$.
My question is:

Can $\phi^*$ be lifted back to a homomorphism (not necessarily to $\phi$) between $E_1$ and $E_2$?
In general, can we find at least one homomorphism $f^*: \hat{E_1} \to \hat{E_2}$ that can be lifted to a homomorphism $f: E_1 \to E_2$?

Assuming $\hat{E_1} =\hat{E_2}$, does the previous question give a positive answer?

For the first question, I saw this post. According to that, we have
\begin{align} & \phi(\hat{E_1}(x,y))=\hat{E_2}(\phi(x), \phi(y)) \\
& \phi^*(\hat{E_1}(x,y))=\hat{E_2}(\phi^*(x), \phi^*(y))
\end{align}
and so I think, we may lift $\phi^*$ to a homomorphism between $E_1$ and $E_2$.
The second question, more general case, I have no idea.
For the third question with the assumption that $\hat{E_1} =\hat{E_2}$. We can consider the $p$-endomorphism $[p]_{\hat{E_1}}=[p]_{\hat{E_2}}$ (when $\hat{E_1}=\hat{E_2}$), then perhaps, we can do a sort of interpolation to extend it to globally as a homomorphism between $E_1$ and $E_2$. But, I do not have a clear mathematical model on this.
I hope I will get some help here. Thanks
Edit: I am editing my question following the comment of Keerthi Madapusi below: since I am considering elliptic curve, the respective formal group laws are 1-dimensional commutative formal group laws which are isomorphic to the additive formal group law, there is hardly non-commutative formal group laws in dimension 1.

Any 1-dimensional formal group law is isomorphic in characteristic $0$ to the additive formal group law, so there is just about maximal loss of information here. The situation in characteristic $p$ is slightly better, however.

@KeerthiMadapusi, my main question is, if I can get a homomorphism between two elliptic curves when I know a homomorphism between the respective two formal group laws. Please ignore the isomorphism in the 3rd question, because in higher dimension there can non commutative  formal group laws which may not isomorphic to each other. Can you comment on the first two questions? What information do you think is lost here?

@NT2024 As mentionned by Keerthi, in characteristic zero, all elliptic curves have isomorphic formal groups. Therefore you can always find a nonzero homomorphism between the formal groups of any two elliptic curves, but you won't be able to lift it if the two curves are not isogenous.

@AntoineLabelle, that is helpful. If the elliptic curves are isogenous then we can lift the homomorphism between the respective formal groups to an isogeny between the elliptic curves. I understand. But if the elliptic curves are not isogenous, then can we find at least one homomorphism between the respective formal groups that can be extended to a homomorphism (not necessarily isogeny) between the elliptic curves, without knowing they are isogenous. If not, what is the obstruction?

@AntoineLabelle, I think knowing the respective formal groups are equal should be enough information. Because the comment of Chris Wurthrich  in this post says that if the respective formal group laws are equal, then the elliptic curves are equal and hence isogenous by default. So we can lift a homomorphism between two formal group laws to a homomorphism between their parent elliptic curves. What do you say?

It is true that the formal group over a field of characteristic zero is a very lossy invariant. However, things are maybe not so bad over a number field (say $K=\mathbf{Q}$). Spread out your elliptic curve to a group scheme over $\mathbf{Z}[1/N]$ for some $N$ and take the associated formal group over $\mathbf{Z}[1/N]$. This should actually be an invariant of $E$, the "formal group up to change of coordinates which has finitely many primes in denominators". And as far as I know (somebody here will be able to give references) by work of Honda (?) this formal group remembers the $L$-series ...

(cont.) ...of $E$ (point counts over all finite fields with large enough characteristic) and hence (by Chebotarev density and Tate conjecture) should be able to determine the curve $E$ up to isogeny.

What I'm saying is that this enriched variant takes values in the category ${\rm FGL}+(\mathbf{Q}) := \varinjlim_N {\rm FGL}(\mathbf{Z}[1/N])$ rather than ${\rm FGL}(\mathbf{Q})$. The natural functor ${\rm FGL}+(\mathbf{Q})\to {\rm FGL}(\mathbf{Q})$ is not an equivalence, precisely because the logarithm/exponential series have too many primes in denominators. (A similar construction should work over any field of char. 0, with colimit taken over all f.g. $\mathbf{Z}$-subalgebras.)

@PiotrAchinger, I guess Thm 4, 5 of this paper of Honda, yes he has worked with elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ and proved that the coefficients of the invariant differential of the formal group law coincide with the coefficients of the L-function of the parental elliptic curve. In details, if $g(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{a_n}{n}x^n$ be the logarithm of the formal group law then the L-function of the elliptic curve is just $L(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_nx^n$. Eichler & Shimura proved same result for abelian variety

This is a temporary answer, please let me know if any argument is incorrect:
SI am answering the third question only. With the assumption $\hat{E_1} =\hat{E_2}$, my answer is yes, provided the other comments are correct.
Answer 1: According to the comments of @Antoine Labelle and this post, if the elliptic curves are isogenous then we can ascend from a homomorphism between the respective formal group laws to that of a homomorphism between the elliptic curve.
On the other hand, according to the comment of @Chris Wurthrich from this post, if two elliptic curve have the same formal group law, then the curves are itself equal and their Weierstras equation is also equal to
\begin{align*}
 f(X,Y)&=X+Y-a_1XY-a_2X^2Y-a_2XY^2-2a_3X^3Y+\cdots+(-2a_1a_3-2a_4)X^4Y+\cdots\\
 &+(-2a_1^3a_3-2a_1^2a_4-4a_1a_2a_3-2a_2a_4-2a_3^2-3a_6)X^4Y+\cdots
 \end{align*}
over any ring of characteristics $0$ or coprime to $6$.
So if the formal group laws are equal, the parental elliptic curves are by default isogenous, and therefore, by the argument of the previous paragraph, we can ascend from a homomorphism between two formal group laws to a homomorphism between the parental elliptic curves.
Answer 2: This second answer is due to the comment of @Piotr Achinger.
Conider the elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$. By the result of Honda, the invariant differential of a formal group law coincides with the $L$-function of the parental elliptic curve. Since the formal group laws are equal, i.e., $\hat{E_1}=\hat{E_2}$, their parental elliptic curves $E_1$ and $E_2$ will have the same $L$-function. Since the $L$-function is an invariant of an isogeny class of elliptic curves, the upshot is that, $E_1$ and $E_2$ are isogenous. Therefore, we can lift a homomorphism $\hat{E_1} \to \hat{E_2}$ into a homomorphism $E_1 \to E_2$.
I think it is also true for elliptic curves over the $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$.
Edit: $p$-adic $L$-functions of elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ also determines isogeny class of elliptic curves as discussed in this post citing the paper
Please leave your comments.

Be careful that @Chris Wurthrich's comment is about actual equality of formal group law (which depend on a choice of coordinate) rather than isomorphism. The actual formal group law is not an invariant of the elliptic curve, only its isomorphism class is.

@AntoineLabelle, absolutely, upon choice of coordinates, one may get a class of isomorphic formal group laws. However, I think that should not be an worry because I am assuming exactly two formal groups (upon choice of coordinates) of the respective elliptic curves are equal. By the way, I don't know any reference of the comment of Chris Wurthrich. I am looking for one
